# Print in custom colors in SWI-Prolog-Editor windows

Tags: prolog

I am using Prolog on swi-prolog-editor for windows. Everything seems to work fine, except I can't write in color (or any font customization) to the console.

For example, I am printing with this:

```
display(E, X, Y) :- at(E, X, Y, Val),Val==r, ansi_format([bold, fg(red)], 'O', []), ansi_format([fg(blue)], '|', []).
display(E, X, Y) :- at(E, X, Y, Val),Val==y, ansi_format([bold, fg(yellow)], 'o', []), ansi_format([fg(blue)], '|', []).
```

Both characters appear, so the `ansi_format` call works. But everything seems to follow the "standard" colors, which means lowercase letters are black while uppercase are blue, and numbers are pink.

[image]

I have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

I tried to add the following line to the top of my file, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(color_term, true).
```

Comment: Is your terminal an ANSI terminal?

Comment: I'm using the default terminal that is included in Swi-Prolog-Editor for Windows
http://arbeitsplattform.bildung.hessen.de/fach/informatik/swiprolog/indexe.html